# How do I find where Python is located on Unix?

Tags: python, shell, unix, directory, shebang

I'm working on a new server for a new workplace, and I'm trying to reuse a CGI script I wrote in Python earlier this year. My CGI script starts off with

```
#!/local/usr/bin/python
```

But when I run this on the new server, it complains that there's no such folder. Obviously Python's kept in a different place on this box, but I've got no idea where.

I haven't done much unix before, just enough to get around, so if there's some neat trick I should know here I'd appreciate it :)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to ask these kinds of questions on unix.stackexchange.com. It's perfectly acceptable here, but unix a good place for these specific not-quite-programming-but-programming-related questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this very reason it is recommend that you change your shebang line to be more path agnostic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

See [this mailing list message](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-June/054816.html) for more information:

> Consider the possiblities that in a different machine, python may be installed at `/usr/bin/python` or `/bin/python` in those cases, `#!/usr/local/bin/python` will fail.
>   For those cases, we get to call the `env` executable with argument which will determine the arguments path by searching in the `$PATH` and use it correctly.
>
> (`env` is almost always located in `/usr/bin/` so one need not worry that `env` is not present at `/usr/bin`.)

Comment: Even on the same machine, when using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) the interpreter path will change.

Answer (score 30):

Try:

```
which python
```

in a terminal.

Comment: Isnt this a more simpler and more accurate answer to the question?

Answer (score 4):

```
# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

*Update*:

I misread. Replace your header with

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

This will pull in the python location from the user that runs the script's environmental settings

Answer (score 4):

Try: `which python` or `whereis python`

Answer (score 3):

It is a good idea to use backticks for header Python script:

```
`which python`
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to solve this problem is with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

which allows for the use of a binary in the PATH in a shebang.